# Wordpress: How to assign user to edit one specified page without plugins

Tags: wordpress

I need a code to assign user to edit one specified page.
user1 can only edit page1
user2 can edit only page2
user3 can edit only page3

Comment: Did you try anything so far ?

Comment: I did find this topic but I didn't understand it.https://www.themightymo.com/2013/05/20/how-to-limit-access-to-wordpress-pages-by-specific-user/